# Why is my derived server control rendering its DataFormatString instead of a formatted data value?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, servercontrols

I have the control below derived from a *BoundField*, used inside a *GridView*, as in the markup below the code. My problem is that the control renders the literal value of it's *DataFormatString*, not a formatted representation of it's data value.

```
public class BoundReportField : BoundField
{
    public override string DataFormatString
    {
        get
        {
            var baseString = base.DataFormatString;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseString))
            {
                return FormatStrings.Currency;
            }
            return baseString;
        }
        set
        {
            base.DataFormatString = value;
        }
    }

    protected override string FormatDataValue(object dataValue, bool encode)
    {
        var val = base.FormatDataValue(dataValue, encode);
        return val;
    }
}

<avm:BoundReportField DataField="BOND_AMOUNT" DataFormatString="R #\,###\,###" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this in your markup:

```
DataFormatString="{0:R #\,###\,###}"
```

**EDIT**
Removed extra quote

Comment: You have an extra quote in there, I believe.

Comment: Ouch, I just seconds ago discovered that myself in the Immediate window and rushed back here to fix my reputation.  Too late.

Comment: @ProfK: Are you talking about the extra quote? That was my fault; your rep is intact ;)

Comment: No, I was talking about the missing argument index, or whatever its real name is, the zero.

Answer (score 1):

sorry my other was wrong, I believe your format string needs to follow this format DataFormatString="{0:D6}" so change it to look like this "{0:R #\,###\,###}"